# How to attach context to analytics events

Tags: analytics, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I was looking to gather some of your collective wisdom in relation to analytics.

Here is an example to illustrate the issue:

> A user opens the application and starts a session.  They open **database A** and perform **action X**.  They then open **database B** and perform **action X** again.

We are tracking an event every time someone does **action X**.

We can easily see that, in this session, **action X** was performed twice.  However, we would like to know that **action X** was performed once *in the context of* **database A** and once *in the context of* **database B**.  This would mean we could filter **action X** events by the database that was being used at the time they were made.

I can think of two approaches:

1. Attach the current database name (and any other context) to the event each time it is fired.  However, this seems wasteful as each event could end up piggy-backing a lot of context around.
2. Send events when the database is changed and somehow infer from the chronology which database was open at the time each **event X** is sent.  This approach is less wasteful but will make analysis more difficult.

Which approach would you suggest?  Are there any other approaches?

Comment: I imagine your events might have more relevant context (eg. user / session)? Would it make sense to have a 'context changed' event with the app context at the time, and refer back to that context from all events?

Comment: Thanks @Zepee.  If implemented carefully, this could be a good way to cut down on the amount of data that needs to be attached to each event, which mitigates the problem in approach 1.  It does make analysis a mite harder though

Comment: The problem with not attaching the data to each event is that it will make it harder to answer questions such as "Are actions in A taking longer than on B?" using the default analysis tools. If you were doing continuous export, and willing to run your analysis from there, then having separate events would work if you just take that data to something like Stream Analytics to generate the data you need.

Comment: Thanks @tomasr.  We are continuously exporting from Application Insights to an Azure storage account and using Power BI to do more complex analysis on that data.  I think Power BI should be sufficiently powerful to do something like Zepee is suggesting.

Comment: @tomasr.  We transform the data by building a model in Power BI rather than using Stream Analytics to transform the data, which seemed more difficult. Do you think this approach is sensible or is there an advantage to using Stream Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

I would most-definitely choose option 1.

First it's simpler - The scenario you described might be simple, but what happens if the user switches context 10 times during a session? Analyzing the data can become very very difficult.

Second, it allows a host of slice-n-dice scenarios later on, as you would be able to easily analyze every event executed in each context.

Answer (score 0):

We use a mix of both patterns internally. For fields that are hyper important (eg. which cluster an error occurred on) we materialize teh cluster id on each event.  This doesn't scale beyond a certain number of categorical fields. We then use a pattern of two identifiers for each event to help us answer deeper questions. First identifier identifies the individual event let's call it EventID.  The second one is the id of the root (the initial activity that caused all the other activities to occur), let's call it session id. This system is very flexible and will scale to your future demands. You will need to post process your events to do the analysis, which will require you to do some work post event capture. Essentially you would need As Assaf notes in his answer, if you're designing for just for this one scenario, hardcoding the database ids into your events makes life easy.  But if it's not a common analysis, you'll end up bloating your events, making overall telemetry management harder.